# JavaScript How to let string to be an array object

Tags: javascript

I got string data like this

```
""id":1,"title":" aaa","context":"aaaaa","countdown":"1","mode":0,"parameter":["none","",""],"alertComp":"",,"
```

and how could I change it to an array object like

```
data = {
        id:1,
        title:" aaa",
        context:"aaaaa",
        countdown:"1",
        mode:0,
        parameter:["none","",""],
        alertComp:""
       }
```

Comment: Where do you get that string from? It looks almost like JSON, but incomplete.

Comment: Your data is a custom format, so you'd need to write custom logic to parse it.  (Or use a standard format.)  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: You'd use `JSON.parse(string)`, but you'd need to remove the last comma and add `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end

Comment: Can you fix whatever is creating the string to create proper JSON instead?

Comment: Also when you have a string that uses `"`s (double quote), you should start and end the entire string with a `'` (single quote), or if you don't want to do that, you could use `\` to escape the added quotation marks, but that's a hassle: `'"bob": "foo", "john": "bar"'` instead of `""bob:": "foo", "john": "bar""` since that doesn't work

Comment: @Samathingamajig That's probably just the way the console is displaying it -- it doesn't change the delimiting quotes depending on the contents, and doesn't escape internal quotes.

Comment: You really need to fix the sender. It's probably not escaping characters properly, either, so anything you write to try to decode it could run into problems.

Comment: The data that you are asking about is not a string. It is itself an object without opening and closing brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have the string:

```js
let rawData = '"id":1,"title":" aaa","context":"aaaaa","countdown":"1","mode":0,"parameter":["none","",""],"alertComp":"",,'
```

First, you need to remove the extra commas at the end:

```js
let commasRemoved = rawData.slice(0, rawData.split``.findIndex((_, ind, arr) => rawData.slice(ind) === ",".repeat(arr.length - ind)));
```

Then you need to add curly braces around the start and the end:

```js
let curlyified = "{" + commasRemoved + "}"; // you could use template literals, but that would look weird because of the { } being important characters
```

Finally, you use `JSON.parse(string)` to get your data:

```js
let parsedData = JSON.parse(curlyified);
```

Putting it all together:

```js
let rawData = '"id":1,"title":" aaa","context":"aaaaa","countdown":"1","mode":0,"parameter":["none","",""],"alertComp":"",,'

let commasRemoved = rawData.slice(0, rawData.split``.findIndex((_, ind, arr) => rawData.slice(ind) === ",".repeat(arr.length - ind)));

let curlyified = "{" + commasRemoved + "}"; // you could use template literals, but that would look weird because of the { } being important characters

let parsedData = JSON.parse(curlyified);

printJSON(parsedData);




// Custom printing function
function printJSON(json) { 
  const pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
  document.querySelector("#container").appendChild(pre);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

pre {
  background: white;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: --calc(100% - 2rem);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it, one approach

```js
const input = `"id":1,"title":" aaa","context":"aaaaa","countdown":"1","mode":0,"parameter":["none","",""],"alertComp":"",,`

console.log(JSON.parse(`{${input.replace(/,+$/,'')}}`))
```